# Can I omit the class name when calling a static method?

Tags: f#

In F#, can I omit the class name when calling a static method?

Example:

In C#, I can do something like:

```cs
using static Bizmonger.Patterns.MessageBus;
...
Publish("SOME_MESSAGE");
```

instead of:

```cs
MessageBus.Publish("SOME_MESSAGE");
```

Can I do something like this in F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In F#, you can use `open` on namespaces (just like `using` in C#) or on modules (which is useful when the API you are calling has been written in F#), but not on static classes (which is what you'd need when calling C# libraries).

One thing that you can do though to make the code a bit shorter is to define a type alias:

```
type M = Bizmonger.Patterns.MessageBus;

// Now you can write just
M.Publish("SOME_MESSAGE")

// Rather than writing the full
MessageBus.Publish("SOME_MESSAGE");
```

There is a [feature request on the F# UserVoice](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6958404-allow-opening-of-static-classes-like-modules) to allow using `open` on static classes (just like in C#) and so if you'd like this to happen, please upvote and comment there.

Comment: The F# UserVoice has been migrated over to GitHub, and any votes left on UserVoice after the migration will not be visible. If anyone finds this answer and wants to vote for this feature, you should do so [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/383) rather than on UserVoice.

Answer (score 0):

I also learned that I could implement a function to serve as a wrapper for clients to call instead.

**Create a wrapper function**

```
module Messages

    open Bizmonger.Patterns

    let Publish (message:string, payload:_) =
        MessageBus.Publish(message, payload)
```

**Client**
Then a client can now invoke a function without specifying a class name.

```
open Messages
...
Publish("SOME_MESSAGE", null);
```

Comment: Since functions are first class citizens in F#, you could also leave out the arguments and write `let Publish = MessageBus.Publish`.