# Why can't F# open static classes?

Tags: .net, f#

I thought modules were compiled to static class .NET IL code. I can `open` namespaces and modules, but why not static classes?

```
printfn "Hello, World!"

open System.Console
WriteLn("Hello, World!")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I omit the class name when calling a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745876/can-i-omit-the-class-name-when-calling-a-static-method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a suggestion for it [on GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/383). The [original suggestion](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6958404), has a comment from Don Syme:

> Yes, this should I suppose be implemented to match the corresponding C# feature, since static classes will begin to be more common coming from the C# world.

I would recommend voting for the issue on GitHub (react with a thumbs up). If you have any comment to add then people may become interested in this again.

Comment: There is also [an issue opened on the fslang-design repo](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/issues) pointing out that this suggestion has been tagged "approved in principle", but nobody has yet written an RFC for it (which is the next step in getting a feature into F#).

Comment: It is implemented in F# 5, I believe

Answer (score 8):

This is now supported, [starting with the F# 5 release](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#open-type-declarations):

```
open type System.Console

WriteLine "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Quite useful stuff!